# Unpack JSON into a single JSON element using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON array that I'm trying to unpack into a single element using jq (needed to be able to be read by another program), but I'm struggling to find the solution.

Considering the following example:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2021-03-24T06:15:42.437Z",
    "facts": {
      "data": [
        {
          "usrwww_size": false
        },
        {
          "architecture": "amd64"
        },
        {
          "bios_version": "rel-1.11.2-0-gf9626ccb91-prebuilt.qemu-project.org"
        },
        {
          "blockdevices": "sr0,vda"
        }
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to make it look like this, as an example:

```
{
  "values": {
    "usrwww_size": false,
    "architecture": "amd64",
    "bios_version": "rel-1.11.2-0-gf9626ccb91-prebuilt.qemu-project.org",
    "blockdevices": "sr0,vda"
  }
}
```

I have tried the following but having no success:

`map (with_entries(select(.key != "facts")) + (.facts | with_entries(.value = .value[])) )`

Output:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2021-03-24T06:15:42.437Z",
    "data": [
      {
        "usrwww_size": false
      },
      {
        "architecture": "amd64"
      },
      {
        "bios_version": "rel-1.11.2-0-gf9626ccb91-prebuilt.qemu-project.org"
      },
      {
        "blockdevices": "sr0,vda"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This only unpacks one value, or multiple in the wrong format if I adjust the `.value[] to .[]`

I've looked at **map**, **filter**, **slurping** but unfortunately haven't been successful. Does anyone perhaps have a solution or can point me in the right direction? I am quite stumped at the moment.

Comment: Your output contains only one value from the input. How are the other six values produced? Is the `.values` object already created and all it needs is to add the property `.usrwww_size` to it?

Comment: Your output is not matching your input

Comment: @axiac, the .values object isn't created - it's just a reference to the location of the key / value in the array. So you can pick a certain key using .value[1] or .value[1:3] to get a bunch but unfortunately it doesn't put it in the JSON format I require.

Comment: Your example output contains `systemd, timezone, uptime` etc - none of which are in the input. It looks like you're trying to turn `.facts.data[]` into a single object but it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks @KarlThornton, I've adjusted my output to avoid confusion. You are correct in saying that I'm trying to turn .facts.data[] into a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it to `add` to get a single object.

```
jq '.[].facts.data | add'

{
  "usrwww_size": false,
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "bios_version": "rel-1.11.2-0-gf9626ccb91-prebuilt.qemu-project.org",
  "blockdevices": "sr0,vda"
}
```

You can add the outer `{ values: }` wrapping needed.

```
jq '{ values: .[].facts.data | add }'

{
  "values": {
    "usrwww_size": false,
    "architecture": "amd64",
    "bios_version": "rel-1.11.2-0-gf9626ccb91-prebuilt.qemu-project.org",
    "blockdevices": "sr0,vda"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Karl Thornton, you're a life saver. The solution works 100% :-)